# CLANG/LLVM : No log2f available Error at backend compilation when created a .ptx file for opencl use

Tags: logging, opencl, llvm

I have this really simple opencl code that I'm trying to cross-compile for .ptx architecture :

```
__kernel void lancementKernel
(
    __global    float           *tabPhotons
)
{
    // idx est l'indice du thread considéré
    unsigned int idx = get_local_id(1) + get_local_size(1) * (get_local_id(0) + get_local_size(0) * ( get_group_id(1) + get_group_id(0) * get_num_groups(1)));
    tabPhotons[idx] = tabPhotons[idx] * log(1.f-(float)idx);
};
```

All it does is calling a log function on a float type.

My generation script is as follow (note that I don't master clang/llvm so I might have made a mistake or forgot something here):

```
clang   \
    -target nvptx \
    -S \
    -std=CL1.1 \
    test.cl -o test.ll \
    -I/usr/local/include/clc/ \
    -include clc/clc.h \
    -Dcl_clang_storage_class_specifiers \
    -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 \
    -emit-llvm

llc -march nvptx  test.ll -mcpu=sm_20 -mattr=ptx30 -o test.ptx
```

Now what I get is an error from the second step (the llc step) which basically says 
"Cannot select: 0x1c8a340: i32 = ExternalSymbol'log2f'"

It appears my log function is #defined as a log2 function (cf clc/math/log.h).

The --save_temps option of clang allow me to look at an intermediate .i file where I see my log function has been replace by a _clc_log2 call.
And the /usr/local/include/clc/math/unary_intrin.inc file give me this clue :

```
__attribute__((overloadable)) float __clc_log2(float f) __asm("llvm.log2" ".f32");
```

From that I tend to think that no llvm.log2  function is implemented for a float type. But there's actually not much else I get so far.

Do you have any idea of what could be (done) wrong ? Or any workaround at least ?

Thanks,

Comment: OpenCL `log2()` function for floats is simply `log2()`. Maybe the includes you are introducing with `include clc/clc.h` are interfering with this, specting a more pure C/C++ compiler, which is not the case. Im just guessing, CLANG is not my expertise. You can also patch it with `log(X)/log(2)` if that trick works.

Comment: @DarkZeros Thanks. Actually i'm using clc to help clang build a binary for OpenCL. Thing is I wish to build an OpenCL binary but not from a computer with an OpenCL SDK installed. That's why I'm using clang to crosscompile and it needs CLC to build for OpenCL. As you said OpenCL specs claim `log2()` for float is `log2()`. I'm really just using `log̀`. But even though clang is looking for `log2f` as log is defined using `log2f` by CLC. I have even tried using `native_log()` but it all come down to `log2f()`. I'm not Clang familiar but I need it to protect my opencl sources by created binaries.